# TypeScript - grab certain text from string

Tags: javascript, string

I have the following text pattern:

`test/something`

The `test/` pattern never changes, only the word that comes after it. I want to grab `something`, basically the word that comes after `test/`. However, it can also come in a sentence, for example:

`Please grab the word after test/something thank you`.

In this case, I want to grab `something` only, not the `thank you`.

I wrote the following code:

```
const start = text.indexOf('test/');
const end = text.substring(start).indexOf(' ') + start;
const result = text.substring(start, end).replace('test/', '');
```

This works, however only if the pattern is in a sentence with spaces. How can I overcome this for **every** case, even if the input string is just `test/something` without anything before or after it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a regular expression instead. Match `test/`, and then match and capture anything but a space, then extract that first capture group.

```js
const text = 'Please grab the word after test/something thank you';
const word = text.match(/test\/(\S+)/)?.[1];
console.log(word);
```

In modern environments, looking behind for the `test/` will be a bit easier - no need for the capture group.

```js
const text = 'Please grab the word after test/something thank you';
const word = text.match(/(?<=test\/)\S+/)?.[0];
console.log(word);
```

Comment: Thank you, that works wonderfully. I definitely need to learn ReGex.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression with a positive lookbehind (`(?<=...)`) and perform a non-greedy capture of anything (`.+?`) up to the first word boundary (`\b`):

```js
const extract = (s) => s.match(/(?<=test\/).+?\b/);

console.log(extract('test/something'));
console.log(extract('Please grab the word after test/something thank you.'));
```